# Get 1D item with 2D coordinates with 1D array beginning at bottom left of 2D array

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, multidimensional-array

How do I get a 1D item which starts at the bottom left of a 2D array after providing 2D coordinates?

```
var width = 3; // the 2D array width
var height = 3; // the 2D array height
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]; // 1D array

console.log(getIndex(0,2));
console.log(getIndex(1,2));
console.log(getIndex(2,2));
console.log(getIndex(0,1));
console.log(getIndex(1,1));
console.log(getIndex(2,1));
console.log(getIndex(0,0));
console.log(getIndex(1,0));
console.log(getIndex(2,0));

//Desired output: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8


function getIndex(x, y) {
  return ... ;   // how????????
}
```

To illustrate, here's the 2D array of the 1D array in the code above:

```
           X
         0---2

   0     6 7 8
Y  |     3 4 5
   2     0 1 2
```

*The numbers in the 2D array represent the position within the 1D index.

Comment: y*numcolumns + x

Comment: Have you made any effort to solve this yourself? All I see is a requirements dump

Comment: I have. Unfortunately, I'm losing my ability to remember, and process thought (and speak).

Comment: @wcochran Although it didn't work, thank you.

Comment: @user2616079 I definitely works (with width as numcolumns). And you picture shows inverse row order

Comment: @MBo Thank you. I must be doing something wrong then. I'm getting output: 6 7 8 3 4 5 0 1 2. I'm trying to get: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8.

Comment: @MBo Here's a jsfiddle (outputs to console): https://jsfiddle.net/otpn5kx3/

Comment: The numbers in the 2D array represent the position within the 1D index.

Comment: call sequence (note x,y order): (0,0) (1,0) (2,0) (0,1) (1,1) (2,1) (0,2) (1,2) (2,2)

Comment: @MBo Thank you. I think I'm not explaining very well. Index 0 of the 1D array MUST correspond to the 0,2 of the 2D array, index 1 of the 1D array MUST correspond to the 1,2 of the 2D array, and so on, as illustrated in the 2D array. I intentionally console logged in the order of the 1D index so the output would show 0 - 8, if done correctly.

Comment: To reverse rows: (height-1-y)*width + x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provide needed access (with reverse row order), you can use such formula:

```
indx =  (height - 1 - y) * width + x
```